# Why doesn't sshd work on my Nixos on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: nixos

My configuration.nix looks like this:

```
{ config, pkgs, lib, ... }:
{
  imports = [<nixpkgs/nixos/modules/installer/cd-dvd/sd-image-aarch64.nix>];
  # NixOS wants to enable GRUB by default
  boot.loader.grub.enable = false;

  # if you have a Raspberry Pi 2 or 3, pick this:
  boot.kernelPackages = pkgs.linuxPackages_latest;

  # A bunch of boot parameters needed for optimal runtime on RPi 3b+
  boot.kernelParams = ["cma=256M"];
  boot.loader.raspberryPi.enable = true;
  boot.loader.raspberryPi.version = 3;
  boot.loader.raspberryPi.uboot.enable = true;
  boot.loader.raspberryPi.firmwareConfig = ''
     gpu_mem=0
  '';   
  services.openssh.enable = true;
  services.sshd.enable = true;
  services.openssh.allowSFTP = true;
  users = {
    mutableUsers = false;
    users = {
      root = {
        hashedPassword = "";
      };
      pi = {
        isNormalUser = true;
        uid = 1000;
        extraGroups = ["wheel"];
        shell = pkgs.zsh;
        hashedPassword = "";
        home = "/home/pi";
      };
    };
  };
}
```

When I try ssh into localhost, it won't connect, and `systemctl status sshd` says that it's dead. When I run `systemctl start sshd`, everything works.

What should I do to get nixos to start sshd at boot?

Comment: You don't need `services.sshd.enable`; it's an alias for `services.openssh.enable`. What does `journal -b -u sshd` have to say?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa "--- No Entries ---"

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Also, when I run `systemctl list-units |rg "ssh"`, I get an empty line

Comment: Does `systemctl list-units|grep ssh` show anything? What's the output of `journalctl -b|grep Reached`?  Also consider posting the contents of `/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service`

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa https://pastebin.com/NiFQvdfV

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/26776#issuecomment-310555407

It worked for me:

```
systemd.services.sshd.wantedBy = lib.mkOverride 40 [ "multi-user.target" ];
```

Comment: Doesn't solve it for me unfortunately:
systemd.services.sshd.wantedBy = lib.mkOverride 40 [ "multi-user.target" ];
services.sshd.enable = true;